# Any way to make r2 big as possible? (non linear curve fitting python)

Tags: python

so what i'm trying to do rn is to make my r2 value big as possible.
rn i got r2 of 0.95, i know it is not good to have a function that have r2 value that big or near 1 when dealing with non linear curve fit but i want near perfect curve fit for this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeLAv.png)

my plot looks somthing like that
i used x^5 + y^5 short form (it was really hard to track all the variables so i used short form..... any nice way to put full form of this?)to make a fit but it seems like it is missing the bottom part, or should i just use other form of equations?

here is my code that i worked on
i used scipy.optimize.curve_fit to solve it, not sure what can i really do from now on

```
def func(data, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p):

# extract data from the single list
x1 = data[0]
x2 = data[1]

return a*data[0]**5+b*x1**4+c*x1**3+d*x1**2+e*x1+f*x2**5+g*x2**4+h*x2**3+i*x2**2+j*x2+k* 
(x1**5)*(x2**5)+l*(x1**4)*(x2**4)+m*(x1**3)*(x2**3)+n*(x1**2)*(x2**2)+o*(x1)*(x2)+p

initialParameters = np.random.rand(16)

# here a non-linear surface fit is made with scipy's curve_fit()
fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = 
initialParameters, maxfev=10000000)

ScatterPlot(data)
SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

print('fitted parameters', fittedParameters)

modelPredictions = func(data, *fittedParameters)


absError = modelPredictions - zData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(zData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```

Comment: What is `r2`? There is no `r2` in your code.

Comment: I think it is `Rsquared`

Comment: If you increase the number of free parameters, e.g. increase the degree of the polynomial fit, it will eventually get very close to 1.

Comment: was thinking about that, is there any clean way to put high degree polynomial fit?
not like what i did?

Comment: look into `numpy.polyfit()` (and `numpy.polyval()` for computing r2)